# Python Function Returning List Objects Out of Order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, iterable-unpacking

I'm relatively new to the Python language.  I'm aware of most of the basic functionality & theory, all the different classes of object and their behavior/properties etc.

Anyway, I was writing basic functions to explore different concepts in practice and get to know the language more intuitively.  One in particular has left me vexed!  Can anyone share any insight into why this result is not as expected?

Here is the code I ran:

```
test_list = [2, 4, 6]
def test_func(k):
    global x, y, z
    for n in k:
        k[k.index(n)] = n * 2
    x, y, z = k
    return k
test_func(test_list)
print(test_list)
print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
```

I would have expected the result to be:

```
[4, 8, 12]
4
8
12
```

However, the actual result is as follows:

```
[8, 4, 12]
8
4
12
```

It seems that the first two items of the list have been swapped.

I can't see what could be causing this?  If anyone can see what's happening here, please share the insight!

Thanks,
Oscar South

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first iteration the first element is changed to 4. In the second iteration the index of 4 is 0 not 1 as you expect.
Try this:

```
test_list = [2, 4, 6]
def test_func(k):
    global x, y, z
    l = list()
    for n in k:
        print(n, k.index(n))
        l.append(n * 2)
    x, y, z = l
    return l
test_func(test_list)
print(test_list)
print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  After reading this it's obvious to me that the .index() method is RETURNING the index rather than iterating through and IDENTIFYING by index.

Answer (score 2):

After first iteration you list look like [4,4,6] so k.index(4) return 0 index and multiple it by 2. So final result is [8,4,12].

Comment: This is the actual reason.

Comment: Makes logical sense now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to do this:

```
test_list = [2, 4, 6]
def test_func(k):
    global x, y, z
    for i in range(len(k)):
        k[i] = k[i] * 2
    x, y, z = k
    return k
```

You're mixing indexes with values, and using `index()` to find the position in an array is incorrect, most of all because you're modifying the list and you'll find the same elements again but in different positions, better use a `range` to iterate over the indexes and retrieve the values.

Also, using globals is not cool. In fact, the whole procedure should be written like a list comprehension instead - simple and idiomatic:

```
[2 * x for x in test_list]
=> [4, 8, 12]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, thanks for the clear explanation.  Thank you especially for sharing info on the list comprehension.  It's another thing I'm working to get confident in at the moment so very useful to see that example.

Answer (score 0):

You can condense the code into a list comprehension and unpacking:

```
test_list = [2, 4, 6]
def test_func(k):
   global x, y, z
   x, y, z = [i*2 for i in k]
   return [x, y, z]
```